# How to install hbase-rpc-client properly?

Tags: node.js, hbase

I am using nodejs and hbase 0.98, so it seems like [hbase-rpc-client](https://github.com/falsecz/hbase-rpc-client) is a good connector. But it can't be installed properly for nodejs after typing `npm install -S hbase-rpc-client`. I have to download it from github and compile it by coffee script. Does anyone know how to install it in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, something went wrong in version 0.1.3, and it is fixed now in 0.1.5. I can install it by npm without any issues.